# What does the A, D and Ms mean when running Duplicity with high verbosity?

Tags: command-line, backup, duplicity

When I run duplicity with the `-v8` switch I get the following output:

```
M home/user/Documents/test.txt
D home/user/VirtualBox VMs/win10/Logs/VBox.log.2
A home/user/.config/VirtualBox/example.log
```

What does the capital letters in front of the paths mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I could not find this documented; probably my Google-fu is
lacking, but the flags you mentioned, `A`, `D`, and `M`, appear to
stand for "added", "deleted", and "modified", respectively, according
to the source code (in `diffdir.py`):

```
log.Info(_("A %s") %
         (util.ufn(delta_path.get_relative_path())),
         log.InfoCode.diff_file_new,
         util.escape(delta_path.get_relative_path()))
```

(...)

```
log.Info(_("D %s") %
         (util.ufn(sig_path.get_relative_path())),
         log.InfoCode.diff_file_deleted,
         util.escape(sig_path.get_relative_path()))
```

(...)

```
log.Info(_("M %s") %
         (util.ufn(delta_path.get_relative_path())),
         log.InfoCode.diff_file_changed,
         util.escape(delta_path.get_relative_path()))
```

Comment: I couldn't find it documented either. Nice find +1